# a way to use bibliography utf8 @string entry keys

Tags: biblatex, unicode, biber

Any suggestions how to allow UTF-8 `@string` macros in the `mwe.bib` file? [lines 537-539]

```
@string{          Uà   =   {Università} #.                           }
@string{        Uàdi   =   Uà#di                                     }
@string{      UàdSdi   =   Uà#degli# {Studi} #di                     }

@PhdThesis{mwe,
  author =   {Some Guy},
  title =    {On something},
  school =   Uàdi# {Padova},
  %school =      UàdSdi# {Bologna},
  year =     2010,
}
```

I have this setup:

```
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{newunicodechar}
\RequirePackage[backend=biber%
,bibencoding=utf8,texencoding=utf8,style=numeric-comp%
,sorting=none,sortcites=true,block=none,indexing=false%
,citereset=none,isbn=true,url=true,doi=true]{biblatex}%
```

and use this in `mwe.tex`:

```
\addglobalbib[datatype=bibtex,type=file]{mwe.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{mwe}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

then run:

```
biber mwe
```

and get:

```
WARN - BibTeX subsystem: /tmp/I5WGNx_9Fe/mwe.bib_16327.utf8, line 537, warning: overriding existing definition of macro "u"
ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: /tmp/I5WGNx_9Fe/mwe.bib_16327.utf8, line 538, syntax error: found "di", expected "="
```

Comment: Don't use accented characters for the string name. Then write ``Universit\`a``, which is completely equivalent to the "accented character" version.

Comment: @egreg: i might as well revert to stock /usr/bin/bibtex; i had in mind some `biber.conf` with perhaps "sourcemap" tricks: say, a preparse that would map `"Uà"` to `"Ua_it"` and then match/replace everywhere (not within "", '') `Ua_it` for `Uà`, in a temporary file?

Comment: This would need hacking in btparse. I already did this for names and entry keys. I would have to look at it.

Comment: I think (private communication) because of your hacked scan.c from btparse you used to allow "~" and "@" in names (which we should allow really as bibtex allows it), you reverse the manual changes I made for UTF-8 a couple of years ago. I bet this works with vanilla Text::BibTeX 0.64

Comment: This should be possible with biber as the backend - can you confirm this? I believe that the problem was a side-effect of your testing with custom btparse to fix another issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your given MWE has several errors, so I tried to correct it. As @egreg mentioned in his comment don't use special characters in string names. If you use something like `di` in a string (see your MWE) it is interpreted as macro. So define a string `di` or just use `{...}` to make clear it should be inserted as normal text. Please see the changed string definitions in my MWE.

I do not know the used language so I just guessed to build the following without an error or warning (the warning that `mwe.bib` (`\jobname.bib` gives `mwe.bib`, if your `tex`file is stored as `mwe.tex`) is overwritten is correct and can be ignored) compiling:

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74037/a-way-to-use-bibliography-utf8-string-entry-keys
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@string{          Ua = {Universit\`a } #.             }
@string{        Uadi = Ua#{ di }                      }
@string{      UadSdi = Ua#{ degli }# { Studi } #{ di }}

@PhdThesis{mwe,
  author = {Some Guy},
  title  = {On something},
  school = Uadi# {Padova},
  year   = 2010,
}
@PhdThesis{mwe1,
  author = {Some Guy},
  title  = {On something},
  school = UadSdi# {Bologna},
  year   = 2010,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber
 ,bibencoding=utf8
 ,texencoding=utf8
 ,style=numeric-comp
 ,sorting=none
 ,sortcites=true
 ,block=none
 ,indexing=false
 ,citereset=none
 ,isbn=true
 ,url=true
 ,doi=true
]{biblatex}%

\addglobalbib[%
   datatype=bibtex
  ,type=file
  ,backend=biber
]{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{mwe} \cite{mwe1}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If I missunderstood you please feel free to change my given MWE.